# Enter a text date (Apr 4, 2021) and display the timestamp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to put a small form on my PHP page with a single input and a submit.
The single input will be for a text date (Apr 4, 2021).
Upon submit, I'd like to just display the timestamp for that input next to the form.

I'm hoping this can be accomplished without having to leave the page as usually I need the timestamp in another form I'm working with at the same time.

I've looked at jquery and ajax, but it's a bit outside my expertise. Can someone point me in the right direction?

What I'm hoping to do:

```
<form id="show_date" method="post">
Payment Date: <input type="text" name="pay_date">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform some AJAX. You're going to want to learn some JavaScript or jQuery. Also post a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you want any further help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Twisty.  I have updated my question with the form i'm hoping to use.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to POST the value to a PHP And the result sof the PHP should be shown in the `result` div. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following jQuery Example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#show_data").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("./calcPayDate.php", {
      pay_date: $("input[name='pay_date']", this).val()
    }, function(results) {
      $("#result").html(results);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="show_date" method="post">
  Payment Date: <input type="text" name="pay_date">
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

jQuery is a Framework for JavaScript. You need JavaScript to be able to perform something in the "background". That something is referred to AJAX. The idea that your browser can send a bit of data to the server and the server can respond without loading an entire web page.

In HTML the default behavior of the Form will send the data, via GET or POST, to another page (usually a server side script).

With JavaScript, or in this case jQuery, we can collect the Value from the form and send just that to your Script. You will then need to handle the data that is returned by the script.

`e.preventDefault` is an Event command that prevent s the default event of the Form.

`$.post()` is a shorthand form of the AJAX POST method in jQuery.

`$("input[name='pay_date']", this).val()` gets the value from a specific input.

`function(results)` is a anonymous callback function that takes the data sent back and assigns it to `results` variable.

`$("#result").html(results);` puts the data into your container.

That's a super crash course for it.

Comment: Twisty, thank you for you help!  It is doing exactly what I wanted it to do! Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Rick great. I hope you will upvote it and mark it as the answer.